# Excel, if value > 0, assign to 1, if not, assign to 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I have a huge spreadsheet with a bunch of columns. For one of the columns, labelled "Clicks," it displays the number of clicks a person has made on a particular email. One person can click 0 or more times. I only care if there has been a click, but not how many. So, I'd like the values to be either 0 or 1.

I tried the following formula, without success (it gives me an error: Clicks must be whole number from -21...... through 21.......).

```
=IF(AND(H2>0), 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MIN, to return 0 or 1:

```
=MIN(H2,1)
```

Comment: @AC_DCEDH that is the joy of Excel, there are usually many ways to do the same thing.  Mine is just less typing but a little harder to follow.

Comment: @AC_DCEDH you should mark kojow7's answer as correct if it is the one you used.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
=IF(H2>0, 1, 0)
```

Basically, the first parameter is the condition, the second parameter is what will be displayed if that condition is TRUE, the third parameter is what will be displayed if the condition is FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved with a Custom format:

```
[>0]1;0
```